# Finding next largest number in a list of list using LINQ (C#)

Tags: c#

Given two lists of lists A and B such that

```
A[0] = {1,2,3,4}

A[1] = {3,4,5,6}

B[0] = {2,5,6,9}

B[1] = {4,5,7,8}
```

how do I use `LINQ` in one line (or as few lines) to return the largest number after the value 1 in all four list A[0],A[1],B[0] and B[1]?  In multi-line, I would do:

```
int num1 = A[0].Find(item => item > 1); (answer is 2)

int num2 = A[1].Find(item => item > 1); (answer is 3)

int num3 = B[0].Find(item => item > 1); (answer is 2)

int num4 = B[1].Find(item => item > 1); (answer is 4)

int finalAnswer = Max(num1,num2,num3,num4); (final answer is 4)
```

The answer should be extendable to any number of list (not just 4).  Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want the first item in each list that isn't 1, or do you want the minimum item that is greater than one?  So for {4, 2, 3, 1} would you want 4 or 2?

Comment: @juharr: I want from each list to find the next value above 1.  then compare all those values from each list and pick the largest one.  i hope that was clear in my example above.

Comment: They should rename this site Cheatonyourhomework.com

Comment: These are not for homework questions, but I can see how they could seem like they were.  I'm a total newbie at LINQ, but some of the responses I'm getting are very useful to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you can concatenate the two collections of arrays together then for each array you'd filter anything that is less than or equal to 1 and order the results and take the first item.  Then take the max of those values.

```
int ans = A.Concat(B).Select(x => x.Where(i => i > 1).OrderBy(i => i).First()).Max();
```

That will throw an exception if any of the arrays do not contain at least one number higher than one.  In which case you might want to use `FirstOrDefault` instead.

```
int? ans = A.Concat(B).Select(x => x.Where(i => i > 1).OrderBy(i => i).FirstOrDefault()).Max();
```

But then you'd have to check if `ans` is `null` if none of the lists have a value greater than 1.

```
if(!ans.HasValue)
    throw new Exception("nothing over one");
int actualAnswer = ans.Value;
```

Comment: great, this works!  Could I use "Find" instead of "Where", "OrderBy" and "First" since "Find" gets the first number in the list that matches the condition?

Comment: A.Concat(B).Select(x => x.Find(i => i > 1)).Max() seems to work for me.  Thx!

Comment: @dynomillie `Find` only works if the lists are already sorted.  Also it will return 0 if no values match the requirement, so you'd need to check for 0 in the case that none of the lists have values over 1.  And finally if you ever changed the requirement to numbers over -1 you would not know if a result of 0 was the actual answer or if that meant there were no values over -1.